# Hide address bar on mobile DNN webApp for iphone and android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, dotnetnuke

I am trying to hide the address bar for both iphone and android (if possible) and have seen multiple threads that used the following code snippet as part of their DNN website by inserting the following into their default.aspx file:

```
<%-- Add mobile bookmark buttons --%>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<%-- Set Apple icons. --%>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="appleIcons" runat="server" />

<%-- Set view port for mobile devices. --%>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">

<%-- Set Apple icons. --%>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/Portals/0/images/apple-touch-icon-114x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/Portals/0/images/apple-touch-icon-114x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/Portals/0/images/apple-touch-icon-114x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/Portals/0/images/apple-touch-icon-114x144.png" />

<%-- Remove URL bar on mobile devices. --%>
<script type="application/x-javascript"> 
    addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout( hideURLbar, 0); }, false); 
    function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } 
</script>
```

I have tested all related threads on this topic. The above worked on a site previously albeit only on iphone but no longer working for me. Appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: To answer my own question (note only works when on mobile webApp not on mobile browser):

```
<%-- Add Apple & Android bookmark buttons --%>    
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<%-- Set view port for Apple & Android devices. --%>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">

<%-- Set Apple & Android icons. --%>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="/Portals/0/images/favicon-96x96.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">

<%-- Set Apple Smart App Bannner by entering app store url in app id field below. --%>
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```